# KendoUI DateTime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using Telerik KendoUI for Asp.net MVC but I can not get this KendoUI grid working.

Everything seems right and I have exactely followed the Telerik documentation. But if I want to save ths insert it is telling me that two inputs aren't of type date but they are though. See it in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behavior indicates that the client-side and server-side cultures are different. As a result, the dates are submitted in a format, which cannot be parsed by the server. Make sure the cultures match:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#match-cultures

Comment: Perfect that did it!! Thank you so mutch, saved my day